# Is there a way to change the default naming convention for new queries in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to change the default naming convention for new queries? `SQLQuery3.sql - serverName(56)` is not a very helpful naming convention for me. Can you change it to automatically include the name of the table being inserted to/altered/selected from if such a table exists? I realize it would be a null value in a query not containing a table name.

I'm also aware of some of the options to rotate through open queries w/ keyboard shortcuts, but that's not great if you have many unnamed queries.

If this is not possible, how do you manage when you have many queries open in SSMS and you need to navigate between them? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to have so many open sessions in SSMS (tabs)?  Also, you should be saving your queries off for future use, that would remove the SQLQuery3.sql, etc

Comment: you could search for SSMS extension. some of them are free for use.. for a while..

Comment: What would you expect it to do? Let's say you open a new query, what is the name? How could is possibly know the table name when you have not yet typed anything? You can always open the `Solution Explorer` to see a list of all open tabs.

Comment: @SeanLange it would be cool if there was an option for it to auto update the query name  when you save/execute/perform some action

Comment: @SQLMason yeah I've started saving the queries but I have so many servers, dbs, and tables I didn't want to have to search for the queries in another spot.

Comment: That kind of thing is not only really strange it would suck the performance out of the tool. It would have to check every single time you run a query to first see if the current tab is from a saved file (because if it is it better not be changing the name), then it would literally have to parse the query to figure out what the first table referenced is. It honestly just doesn't make any sense as it would be so arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove alot of the noise from the tabs.
See https://therightjoin.wordpress.com/2017/02/19/customise-ssms-query-tab-information/

You can also pin query tabs into a 2nd layer, see the options in ssms